# What is the CSS @Page Property Selector to access the last page of the PDF? Do we have :last() selector in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to access the last page of a PDF using the selectors available in @page property. However, all I could find is the :first() selector.

I would like to know if we have any selector called :last() for the @page property. Or do we have any workaround to access the last page of the PDF?

Note: I am working with creation of PDF using @page property in Salesforce. For your information the Visualforce Engine supports 2.1 CSS only.

So I am looking forward for a workaround to access the last page before the PDF is generated.

Comment: OK, so you've tried, how about posting the code snippet of what you've tried?